# What a Symbolic Model Looks Like

Tags: logic, formal-verification, model-checking, symbolic-execution

I am trying to understand how Symbolic Execution engines work. [This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.00502.pdf) surveys the techniques using C. They mention about symbolic memory:

> **3.1 Fully Symbolic Memory**
>
> At the highest level of generality, an engine may treat memory addresses as fully symbolic...
>
> Representing memory in a compact form. This approach was taken in [32], which maps
>   symbolic – rather than concrete – address expressions to data, representing the possible
>   alternative states resulting from referencing memory using symbolic addresses in a compact,
>   implicit form

[This paper](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/saswat/research/SymExAbstraction.pdf) also goes a little into symbolic heaps for Java:

> **4.1 Symbolic State Representation**
>
> A symbolic state s consists of a symbolic heap H, the
>   valuation of the primitive typed fields, the path condition
>   PC and the program counter.

I am wondering what *in practice* this means, this symbolic heap. To me this means that all of the data structures used in the symbolic execution will be using symbolic memory rather than the actual memory. Which means structures like arrays need to have **symbolic models**. I am wondering at a high level what these models look like. I don't see how you can "symbolically model the array length". In my head it is an integer so it will be an integer value. But as a symbolic value, wondering what this means. I don't see it yet. Wondering if one could explain at a high level how you would symbolically model some data structures like arrays or a struct with some different field values, so it would be useful in symbolic execution.

[This older paper](https://yurichev.com/mirrors/king76symbolicexecution.pdf) mentions:

> One can also
>   define an alternative "symbolic execution" semantics
>   for a programming language where the real data objects
>   need not be used but can be represented by arbitrary
>   symbols.

Not sure how this looks.

Comment: Wikipedia entry contains a very simple example of a symbolic execution, look at it first.

Comment: I looked there and it helps, but I still don't see how a data structure would look like for an array, for example.

Comment: You may now try to read "Array representation in symbolic execution"
by Alberto Coen-Porisini and Flavio De Paoli" (if you have access to some scientific database)

Comment: I don't have access unfortunately :/

Comment: Each day can be a Christmas day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fully documented open source example of a symbolic execution engine is JPF - Symbolic Pathfinder. It executes on the Java virtual machine level. It should  answer your questions also on complexer data structures like arrays or arrays of objects.

A very good publication is here:
“Symbolic PathFinder: Integrating Symbolic Execution with Model Checking for Java Bytecode Analysis” in Automated Software Engineering Journal 20(3) 2013
https://ti.arc.nasa.gov/publications/5269/download/

Here you can see a detailed example (section 4.9) on how the concrete code is "rewritten" and transformed into symbolic code. Especially how the stack and heap memory and the code-conditions depending on this symbolic memory is handled (Fig. 6+7). You can't simply separate the memory from the conditional path execution.

Very simplified: The conditions are replaced by a loop over all "symbolic" branches (nondeterministic choice). The memory is replaced by symbolic values (like you mentioned it - propagated here via so called attributes) and constraints on these values depending on the branch-loop. A constraint solver is used to further reduce impossible branches (backtracking) and to solve the constraints finally.

Another very good hands-on example for .Net-code is to run Microsoft SpecExplorer (XRTs) in the full symbolic mode using "Combination.KeepUnexpanded". In the resulting explored traversed path graph you can see a nice example how the symbolic memory and constraints are represented. Unfortunately XRTs is not open source.

P.S.:
Indeed The representation of the symbolic variables is one of the big challenges. Here are some very good publications:

- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2006/01/XRTSoftMC05.pdf
- https://dspace.cuni.cz/bitstream/handle/20.500.11956/2087/DPTX_2015_2_11320_0_477386_0_179174.pdf?sequence=1
- https://dspace.cvut.cz/bitstream/handle/10467/76321/F8-DP-2018-Husak-Robert-thesis.pdf?sequence=-1&isAllowed=y

Answer (score 0):

"The array X has size 100, and the element in position 5 has value 7" is a symbolic representation of an array.
The key point of symbolic representation is that you focus on expliciting only what matters.

If you want to represent an even more geneic array, you can make also its size symbolic, by saying "X has size L" and during your analysis you might figure out that L=100 or L>90.

How much you capture of different data structures depends on what you want to do. Is a linked list a bunch of memory areas or something more?